# neo4j how to return all node labels with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I can't find how to return a node labels with Cypher.

Anybody knows the syntax for this operation?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is a function labels(node) that can return all labels for a node.

Answer (score 109):

To get all distinct node labels:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN distinct labels(n)
```

To get the node count for each label:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN distinct labels(n), count(*)
```

Comment: `MATCH n RETURN DISTINCT LABELS(n)` is 8 characters less to type :)

Comment: Agree with @FLekschas and moreover, Neo recommends that you use `MATCH` for newer Neo4j databases because `START` is for legacy indexes.

Comment: `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError Parentheses are required to identify nodes in patterns, i.e. (n) ...` (v. 3.1.1)

Comment: This question also has `neo4j` tag in addition to `cypher`. The shortest to write (and fastest to execute!) query for getting all distinct node labels is `CALL db.labels` -- at least since `neo4j` 3.0, see also CALL page in `neo4j` [manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/clauses/call/)

Comment: How can I return labels for a list of nodes?

Answer (score 45):

Neo4j 3.0 has introduced the procedure `db.labels()` witch return all available labels in the database. Use:

```
call db.labels();
```

Comment: this is the most efficient approach

Comment: `call` is `4ms` vs `15ms` for `MATCH (n)` on my digitialocean test DB.

*One note*: I have hierarchical labels, and `MATCH` returns them as `["RawFile", "RawPhoto"]`, where `call` only returns the flattened list.

Comment: Why was this so hard to find.

Answer (score 25):

If you want all the individual labels (not the combinations) you can always expand on the answers:

```
MATCH (n)
WITH DISTINCT labels(n) AS labels
UNWIND labels AS label
RETURN DISTINCT label
ORDER BY label
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 START n=node(*) RETURN labels(n)
```

Comment: Results on this are currently a nightmare. Returns 1 row for every node. `START n=node(*) RETURN DISTINCT(labels(n))` returns the same as `MATCH (n) RETURN distinct labels(n)`, but takes ~10 times as long (on my db)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Java API, you can quickly get an iterator of all the `Label`s in the database like so:

```
GraphDatabaseService db = (new GraphDatabaseFactory()).newEmbeddedDatabase(pathToDatabase);
ResourceIterable<Label> labs = GlobalGraphOperations.at(db).getAllLabels();
```

Comment: "with Cypher" -- OP

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the labels of a specify node, then use `labels(node)`; If you only want to get all node labels in neo4j, then use this function instead: `call db.labels;`, never ever use this query: `MATCH n RETURN DISTINCT LABELS(n)`. It will do a full table scan, which is very very slow..

Answer (score 0):

match(n) where n.name="abc" return labels(n)

it returns all the labels of the node "abc"