# How to get a list of all relationships, nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to get all nodes or all relationships or both together in Neo4j? The closest I've seen is the [`relationships()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-relationships), for example:

```
MATCH p = (a)-->(b)-->(c)
WHERE a.name = 'Alice' AND c.name = 'Eskil'
RETURN relationships(p)
```

However, I'm looking to do something similar to:

```
SHOW TABLES
```

Where it would just list everything. Is it possible to do something like that not at the query-level but for an entire database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [neo4j how to return all node labels with Cypher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18398576/neo4j-how-to-return-all-node-labels-with-cypher)

Comment: @Richard thanks for pointing that out. How do you get the relationships/edges then?

Comment: To get a list of [Relationship Types](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/scalar/#functions-type).

Comment: `SHOW TABLES` just list the tables but not the contents. If you want the list of relationship types, you can refer to https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/#procedure_db_relationshiptypes , or you can refer to https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/procedures/#procedure_db_schema_visualization to view the db schema

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

**List all nodes**

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN n
```

**List all relationships**

```
MATCH ()-[r]->()
RETURN r
```

**List both**

```
MATCH (s)-[r]->(e)
RETURN s,e,r
```

Comment: with distinct. If there are a million nodes of type Person, I want it to return ['Person'] and not 1M items.

Comment: Ok, I missed that you want to return node labels and relationship types. How about this:
`MATCH (n), ()-[r]->()
RETURN COLLECT(distinct labels(n)) AS nodeLabels, COLLECT(distinct type(r)) AS relationshipTypes`